# Select product based on price and categories -SQL Request

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, left-join

I'm fairly new to SQL and would like to get help with a query.

I have the following tables:

```
#product
 ------------------------------------------
| product_id | title | date | price | lang |
 ------------------------------------------

#product_to_categories
 -------------------------------
| id | category_id | product_id |
 -------------------------------

#category
 --------------------
| category_id | name |
 --------------------
```

I would like to select all the products which have a specific lang and  belonging to a specific category.

Is there a way to do in one request, or shall I first select all the product which have a specific lang and then look one by one if they are in the product to categories table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See an interactive example in this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/87e271/10):

```
SELECT 
  p.title,
  c.name as category
FROM product p
INNER JOIN product_to_categories pc on pc.product_id = p.product_id
INNER JOIN category c on c.category_id = pc.category_id
WHERE p.lang='en' and c.category_id in (3, 4)
```

An example of the results would look as follows:

```
---------------
title | name
---------------
Apple | Green
Apple | Red
Kiwi  | Green
```

## Grouping categories

If you want to group the contents, `postgres` (Since 9.0) has a [built in function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) called `string_agg` that you could use if you manipulate the script as follows:

```
SELECT 
  p.title,
  string_agg(c.name, ', ') as category
FROM product p
INNER JOIN product_to_categories pc on pc.product_id = p.product_id
INNER JOIN category c on c.category_id = pc.category_id
WHERE p.lang='en' and c.category_id in (1, 3)
GROUP BY p.product_id, p.title
ORDER BY p.title
```

See interactive example in this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9340d/4).

An example of the results would look as follows:

```
---------------
title | name
---------------
Apple | Red, Green
Kiwi  | Green
```

## Explanation of Joins

Understanding SQL joins is simpler when you understand how you want to interact with your result sets. Here is a [great reference](http://www.halfgaar.net/sql-joins-are-easy). *Images are referenced from this post by halfgaar.*

- **INNER JOIN** returns a set where both result sets intersect.

[image: Depiction of an INNER JOIN]

- **LEFT OUTER JOIN** returns a set where all rows in the left result set are present but only rows from the right set that intersect with the left.

[image: Depiction of a LEFT OUTER JOIN]

- **RIGHT OUTER JOIN** does the same as the LEFT OUTER JOIN but in reverse.

[image: Depiction of a RIGHT OUTER JOIN]

- **FULL OUTER JOIN** combines both sets into one big resultset.

[image: Depiction of a FULL OUTER JOIN]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However if a product is affected to several categories, how will it be returned? Several row of the same product with for each one a category name ?

Comment: I've updated the answer to give a sample of the results although you could run it using the SQL fiddle link referenced in the article. 

If there are multiple categories for a product it will return multiple rows of that product. Could you supply an example of how you want your data to be returned?

Comment: Thanks for the SQL Fiddle, that's very great. Somehow I would like to avoid the duplicate row of the same product and if a product belong to severa categories , then group all the categories name in the row of the product separated by a coma. I guess this is where the GROUP By clause is useful no ?

Comment: Have a look at the updated fiddle as well as the updated post with the grouping T-SQL. Is this closer to what you wish to achieve? I did use a `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Note that you can override the seperator when using the `group_concat` built in function. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: Thanks that looks great (however the fiddle is not updated). I'm using postgresql, I'm not sure that group_concat is existing, however I will have a look for an equivalent. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115016/discussion-between-cbouwer-and-anselme).

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT     dbo.product.lang, dbo.product.product_id, dbo.product.title, dbo.product.date, dbo.product.prize, dbo.category.category_id AS Expr1
FROM         dbo.product_to_categories INNER JOIN
                      dbo.product ON dbo.product_to_categories.product_id = dbo.product.product_id INNER JOIN
                      dbo.category ON dbo.product_to_categories.category_id = dbo.category.category_id
WHERE     (dbo.product.lang = N'desiredang') AND (dbo.category.category_id = 'desired category id')
```

Comment: thanks a lot! Is there a way to provide an array of category id in the where clause ?

Comment: (dbo.category.category_id in (id1,id2,id3,od4))